# Android support v7 app cannot be resolved error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I am running eclipse juno on a 64 bit windows 8.1 machine, I have imported a project into eclipse, but the error i am facing is 
[image: On importing the project]
On reading about it, I came across the solution that I am supposed to configure the build path manually, 
but I am unable to do so since, 
[image: Configure build path]
[image: On clicking add]
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Create a new test project with any name and then you find the appcombact_v7 library so just have to include that library in your imported project

Comment: from your pictured project i dont see the library? download the v7 library and import it to your workspace.. and open your support library folder and copy the the v7 lib and add it to your project in the libs folder, then, right click on it and add to build path.. Kaboom!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your screen shot I can see app-compact project imported; This should cause your problem. In better word: when you are using app.support.v7 libraries you must import app-compact project in your workspace and add it as your project dependency.

follow below link of developers:

```
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
```

**Especially this part will help you:**

1- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.

2- Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:

2- Select File > Import.

3- Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.

4- Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the appcompat project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.

5- Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.

6- In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.

7- Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.

In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
        Uncheck Android Dependencies.
        Click OK to complete the changes.

You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.

Add the library to your application project:

1- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.

2- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.

3- In the Library pane, click the Add button.

4- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.

5- In the properties window, click OK.

**Update**

Also you can import and copy the 'appCompact' library directly to your workspace and then add it as you project dependency. Please follow steps in this guide in order to adding the 'appCompact' by this way:

https://yassirh.com/2014/01/getting-the-android-navigation-drawer-to-work-on-old-versions-of-android/

(The above link is in order to using navigation drawer in older version but same objects are using appCompact and using it have same solution for both)

Comment: followed it step by step, now the cross on the project in the project explorer has become an exclamation mark and the errors in the code are still unresolved, although in the project explorer, the files don't show any errors

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**

Make sure that you've installed already the following libraries `Android Support Library`, `Android Support Repository` and `Google Repository` by checking in the Extra folder by openning the **Android SDK Manager** in eclipse.

**if it is already installed then add them to Eclipse**

```
Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code into workspace.
```

Add `/android/adt-bundle/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` to your `Eclipse` workspace.

**Right click on the project in Eclipse and select properties.**

```
Select Android -> Library -> Add.
Select appcompatv7 project and Save.
```

**Use import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar to import Action bar in activities and fragments.**