# ActionBarActivity and ActionBar.TabListener is deprecated inside Android Tab Fragment ( Eclipse ApI 22 )

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am implementing the `ActionBar.TabListener` in My Tab Fragment .

I updated the API 22, After updating it showing `ActionBar.TabListener` and `ActionBarActivity`  is **deprecated.**

Like this i have used in my code

```
public class Tabview_Landing extends ActionBarActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
}
```

[Link](http://javapapers.com/android/android-tab-layout-with-swipe-views/) help me to solve this.

Comment: What exactly is your issue?  Are you aware of what depreciated APIs are?

Comment: My issue is Actionbar tablistener is not working , after Updating the API 20 to API22

Comment: which library support you given ? see this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: ActionBarActivity  replace with AppCompatActivity and try.

Comment: it extends AppcompatActivity

Comment: @AnkitkumarMakwana Any Alternative solution instead of changing Actionbar Tabs to Tablayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82606/discussion-between-kumar-and-ankitkumar-makwana).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` was replaced by `AppCompatActivity`.

Action bar tabs can be replaced by:

- [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from the Android Design Support Library, with or without [a `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html); or
- a `ViewPager` and your favorite other tab solution for it, whether that be `PagerTabStrip` or [any number of third-party tab implementations](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111); or
- [`FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Comment: i have replaced ActionBarActivity  by AppCompatActivity ,but still ActionBar.TabListener is deprecated

Comment: Ok sir. iam trying to add Tablayout instead of actionbar Tabs.