# ActionBar.TabListener is deprecated what should use instead

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am trying to use `ViewPager` with `ActionBarTabs`. I referred to some examples and followed them. but the `TabListener` and `ActionBar.Tab` used in the below code are deprecated and i do not know what should i use as alternative?

**Please provide an example for the new API**

> My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
```

**gradle**:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.vpager_00"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    ccompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    }
```

Comment: `TabLayout` from support and `ViewPager` for sliding tabs

Comment: @NJNileshJ should i download specific library for that?? I am using android studio

Comment: I have posted answer please check

Comment: @user2121 - Check my answer, but, there are two things you may want to know, `ccompile` duplicate `c` and try to use the latest supportlibrary.`23.1.1`

Comment: @LinX64 ok, but when i used 23.1.1 FragmentStatePagerAdapter class is undefined

Comment: So, perhaps you didn't define that and your answer was about: `ActionBar.TabListener` `is deprecated what should use instead` and you should use `Ask question` and paste your codes by creating an another question.maybe, you missed something, btw,, that's the another problem/issue.

Answer (score 1):

[TabLayout official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

compile dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

include in your layout like

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### see [tutorial link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Comment: can u please have a look at gradle file posted above...because AppCompatActivity is not recognised and R class as well

Comment: Try clean your project

Answer (score 0):

You use use `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` instead. (Doc : [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

Basically, add `TabLayout` view and `ViewPager` to your main screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And create an adapter extends from `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Please see this guide for how to implement the `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`.

> https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer:

[Android Studio: ActionBar.TabListener does not work with AppCompatActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203624/android-studio-actionbar-tablistener-does-not-work-with-appcompatactivity/35203962#35203962)

**See:** http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html

> ***This interface is deprecated.*** Action bar navigation modes are
>   deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider
>   using other [common navigation patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) instead.

And:

> **Action bar tabs can be replaced by:**
>
> - `TabLayout` from the `Android Design Support Library`, with or without a
>     [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html); or
> - a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and your favorite other tab solution for it, whether that
>     be `PagerTabStrip` or [*any number of third-party tab implementations*](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111); or
> - [`FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

**Check this link:** [ActionBarActivity and ActionBar.TabListener is deprecated inside Android Tab Fragment ( Eclipse ApI 22 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268916/actionbaractivity-and-actionbar-tablistener-is-deprecated-inside-android-tab-fra)