# Android Support Library : The import android.support.v7.internal cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

My has was running fine till I updated the support library.

- The import android.support.v7.internal cannot be resolved
- OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
- AdapterViewCompat cannot be resolved to a type

Now I'm getting the following error in the line:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener;

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener, android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterViewCompat<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
         navigateTo(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        displayMenuView(position);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours.Also tried an old support lib but didn't work.

Comment: refer [this for android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol) and  [this for eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved). hope this helps

Comment: You should not be trying to use anything in the `internal` package.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I've already tried that too. Seen this question already. But it also didn't solve.

Comment: @JaredBurrows What should I try then?

Comment: @BulletProof47 What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'm trying to add click listener to navigation drawer item using support library. Thanks

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/MainActivity.java#L113.