# Unable to add appcompat support library in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My project(eclipse) has dependencies on `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`. I tried the following.

1. Tried to add the library in my project's Java build path. Didnt work.
   Also I observed something weird. The path for support libraries referenced elsewhere in SO is Android\sdk\extras\android\support\appcompat

However in my SDK the path is the following.

Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support

May I ask why is that so?

2. Also I copied the appcompat jar file into the libs folder of my project. Still it didnt work.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer

[The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved)

After you add appcompat_v7 to your dependencies, be sure that the `libs` folder from your project are empty. By default, an android-support-v4.jar is created when you define your project, so this will cause conflict when you declare appcompat_v7 library as your dependency.

So, the first thing you need to do is check the folder `.../My_Project/libs` and fearlessly delete  the file `android-support-v4.jar`.

Then, add the appcompat_v7 library as a dependency of your project:
To do this, if you are using Eclipse:

1. Right click in your project folder, located in the Navigator.
2. Click in properties, in the final of the list.
3. In the Properties window, select the Android option (left menu).
4. In the box Library, add your new reference.

Support Library Setup - 
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Yes. I did check this. To import the project, should I extract the appcompat-v7-21.0.0.aar file and then import to eclipse? Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: and also make new project.... than created the appcompatlibraray and add this... to your project......

Comment: "u can update the android supoort libarary to your sdk manager". i didnt get this. Android support libs are already installed.what i asked was, the appcompat-v7 folders are located as .aar files in the support directory. I have mentioned the path in my question.Should I extract them and then import them or create a new project with those?

Answer (score 0):

Just import the appcompact library in your workspace then simply add this library in your project from properties .
It works for me. I using this. I also provide you library.