# Eclipse Neo won't recognize android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity when changing Android SDK Manager path

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, appcompatactivity

I have changed the path of Android SDK Manager (because I have almost no disk space in C:) to D:.
So, the path to the SDKs is D:/Android/sdk/...

I have downloaded every extra package from the android SDK Manager.

I'm usig Eclipse Neo to make some apps, ad the thing is that Eclipse don't recogize the import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;.It says "The import android.support cannot be resolved".

I was trying to follow the steps here: [The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved) , but it looks like the support libraries have changed the path, because is no longer in /sdk/extras/android/support... but in \sdk\sources\android-22\android\support\v7\app (at least that is my path of AppCompatActivity).

Anyway, i tried to add that path to the libraries, and I can't add them.
I did: Right click to project -> properties -> Android, and in library section, i press "add", but nothing shows up.

https://s12.postimg.org/rpjmbvxzh/Android_library.png

I tried adding the path in the Java Build Path, but Eclipse won't find the AppCompatActivity.java file.

The path of the Android SDK is configured correctly in Eclipse.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?
Sorry my bad English.

**EDIT:** I moved to Android Studio. It was for the best.

Comment: High time to move on to Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You have to have your android sdk  and eclipse workspace in same directory partition. so if you have it located in C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat, then you have to move your own project somewhere on drive C:\ (e.g. C:\Users\User\workspace)

Go to File -->Import -->Import the library project into your workspace(select the project exists here C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat).

Then Right Click on your project-->Select Android --> Add-->Select the library project you have imported.

don't forget to checkmark the library project in Project-->Right Click-->Properties-->Java Build Path--->Order and Export

Comment: Let me know if this didn't worked for you? Else please accept the answer

Comment: Hi.
The Android SDK, ad the project are both in disk D:
Android SDK path: D:/Android/sdk
Project path: D:\EclipseWorkspace\project

I don't have an option to import library as you say in this step: "Go to File -->Import -->Import the library project into your workspace(select the project exists here C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat)."

Comment: And in fact, I don't have the \sdk\extras\support...path. I have this path (wich i don't know if this is something wrong): \sdk\sources\android-22\android\support\v7\app

Thanks for your response

Comment: I never said \sdk\extras\support. Please check again, it will be inside extras\android\support as mentioned by me, above as well. Ignore the import library thing. Just go ahead and import an existing project v7. I believe you will get an option for Import under File menu. Inside that select Import Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Comment: Hi again. I don't have that folder neither. What I have is this:
https://s16.postimg.org/u3br87thx/Tree.png

And inside the las folder there are only .aar, .jar, .md5.... and no project files :(