# I am getting error "The import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved" while importing java files of Android studio

Tags: java, php, android

I tried importing the Android studio java file to my eclipse 
I tried all possible solutions for "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" error

Comment: My guess is that your Gradle dependencies need to be updated.

Comment: Answer is already available in StackOverflow. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651232/the-import-android-support-v7-app-cannot-be-resolved